# Using interval-censored cox regression with missing data (using icenReg)

Tags: r, cox-regression

Using the icenReg package, one is able to calculate an interval-censored cox regression using ic_sp and model = 'ph'. However, I struggle with the problem of the left and right censoring one has to specify in ic_sp [ic_sp(cbind(left, right)]. I have 5 measurement points for all of my individuals, but some individuals are missing e.g. on the in-between measurement points 2, 3 or 4.

I've got the following questions:

1. As all of my indviduals entered the study at Baseline (measurement point 1), would the left censoring in ic_sp always be baseline?
2. as some individuals are missing different measurement points, what is the correct way of programming the right censoring? E.g., imagine data are available for one individual for measurement point 1,2,3 and 5. So would the right censoring be measurement point 5? What about the missing data point 4? Is there any way of incorporating such missing data?

I already tried doing the analysis without considering missing data, however, the results differ significantly between the dataset with missing data and the imputed dataset.